# what is Instagram API basic access in sandbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram, instagram-api

I try to use instagram API in sandbox.
I use Ruby with `gem 'instagram'`
But I can only call method

```
Instagram.user_recent_media( {:count => 5})
def user_recent_media(*args)
      options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
      id = args.first || "self"
      response = get("users/#{id}/media/recent", options)
      response
    end
```

like  `@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media( {:count => 5})`
I try to call other method like

```
def follow_user(id, options={})
  options["action"] = "follow"
  response = post("users/#{id}/relationship", options, signature=true)
  response
end
```

get

**Instagram::BadRequest in HomeController#index**

> GET
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user_ID]/follows.json?access_token=[Access_token]&max_id=10:
>   400: This request requires scope=follower_list, but this access token
>   is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your
>   application with scope=follower_list to be granted this permissions.

Is there any method I can use ??

[instagram-ruby-gem API](https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem/tree/master/lib/instagram/client)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to register your application with Instagram [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) and hope they accept it. There isn't a way around this.

Here's a little reading on how they basically said "buzz off" to third party app developers [http://www.businessinsider.com/instagram-made-a-change-that-stopped-lots-of-third-party-apps-from-working-2016-6](http://www.businessinsider.com/instagram-made-a-change-that-stopped-lots-of-third-party-apps-from-working-2016-6%20'here')

Comment: So I have to register to get more Permission ?
the link down below is invild 
http://www.businessinsider.com/instagram-made-a-change-that-stopped-lots-of-third-party-apps-from-working-2016-6

Comment: You have to register and hope Instagram deems your app as a reasonable use of their API (hint - they probably wont). Here's a different link https://techcrunch.com/2015/11/17/just-instagram/